# Merge two multidimensional arrays with same key pair

Tags: php

I have two multidimensional arrays with same number of keys as below

```
Array
(

[2012035] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => ABC
        [last_name] => DEF
    )

[2012045] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => GHI
        [last_name] => JKL
    )

[2012046] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => MNO
        [last_name] => PQR
    )

[2012050] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => STU
        [last_name] => VWX
    )
)
```

and

```
Array
(

[2012035] => Array
    (
        [01-07-2015] => 123 
        [02-07-2015] => 456 
    )

[2012045] => Array
    (
        [01-07-2015] => 789 
        [02-07-2015] => 101112 
    )

[2012046] => Array
    (
        [01-07-2015] => 131415 
        [02-07-2015] => 161718 
    )

[2012050] => Array
    (
        [01-07-2015] => 192021 
        [02-07-2015] => 222324
    )
)
```

Now I want the output as below

```
Array
(
[2012035] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => ABC
        [last_name] => DEF
        [01-07-2015] => 123 
        [02-07-2015] => 456 
    )

[2012045] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => GHI
        [last_name] => JKL
        [01-07-2015] => 789 
        [02-07-2015] => 101112
    )

[2012046] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => MNO
        [last_name] => PQR
        [01-07-2015] => 131415 
        [02-07-2015] => 161718
    )

[2012050] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => STU
        [last_name] => VWX
        [01-07-2015] => 192021 
        [02-07-2015] => 222324
    )
)
```

I am able to do it using foreach in PHP .

But is there any built in PHP function that can do this work with out using foreach?

Comment: If your arrays had string keys (instead of integers) I'd say `array_merge_recursive` would do the trick.

Comment: @agmangas  without  a loop, I would say no `array_merge_recursive `wouldn't do the trick, but with a simple for loop, `array_merge_recursive`  is definitely one possible solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this can work for you:

```
$arr_1 = array(333 => array('a1' => 1));
$arr_2 = array(333 => array('a2' => 2), 444 => array('a3' => 3));

$arr_res = array_replace_recursive($arr_1, $arr_2);
var_dump($arr_res);
```